# GROUP BY and ORDER BY problem

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, group-by, aggregate, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE cmap5 (
   name     varchar(2000),
   lexemes  tsquery
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS synonyms_all_gin_tsvcolumn (
   cid       int NOT NULL,  -- REFERENCES pubchem_compounds_index(cid)
   name      varchar(2000) NOT NULL,  
   synonym   varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
   tsv_syns  tsvector,
   PRIMARY KEY (cid, name, synonym)
);
```

My current query is:

```
SELECT s.cid, s.synonym, c.name, ts_rank(s.tsv_syns,c.lexemes,16) 
FROM synonyms_all_gin_tsvcolumn s, cmap5 c
WHERE c.lexemes @@ s.tsv_syns
```

And the output is:

```
cid     |  synonym                              | name (query)              | rank
5474706 | 10-Methoxyharmalan                    | 10-methoxyharmalan        | 0.0901673
1416    | (+/-)12,13-EODE                       | 12,13-EODE                | 0.211562
5356421 | LEUKOTOXIN B (12,13-EODE)             | 12,13-EODE                | 0.211562
 180933 | 1,4-Chrysenequinone                   | 1,4-chrysenequinone       | 0.211562
5283035 | 15-Deoxy-delta-12,14-prostaglandin J2 | 15-delta prostaglandin J2 | 0.304975
5311211 | 15-deoxy-delta 12 14-prostaglandin J2 | 15-delta prostaglandin J2 | 0.304975
5311211 | 15-deoxy-Delta(12,14)-prostaglandin J2| 15-delta prostaglandin J2 | 0.304975
5311211 | 15-Deoxy-delta-12,14-prostaglandin J2 | 15-delta prostaglandin J2 | 0.304975
5311211 | 15-Deoxy-delta 12, 14-Prostaglandin J2| 15-delta prostaglandin J2 | 0.304975
```

I would like to return the name matches of all rows in `cmap5` in my main table ranked by the `ts_rank()` function but for each row in `cmap5` I want to:

- select only the best X `cid`s to each query (`group by cid`)
- or `ORDER BY my results as 1+ts_rank/count(cid)`

To get the best match I tried to add `select distinct on c.name`, but when the rank is the same I want to get the `cid` with more matches to the query. I have tried adding a simple group by at the end of the query but I get an error, how could I do this?

Added comments:

On one hand for those results whose rank is the same, eg. above `5283035` and `5311211`, get `5311211` as top result because that `cid` has more hits than `5283035`, so I sort of want to take into account the number of hits / `cid` in the rank, like final_rank = 1+ts_rank(cid)/no. of hits(cid).

On the other hand I want to get the first `X` cids per query name. If I use `LIMIT X` it returns the first `X` results of the entire query table, not the first `X` *per name* (row) of the query table as I want.

Answer (score 9):

First off, your `PRIMARY KEY` spanning two `varchar(2000)` columns seems extremely expensive. If you use your PK for anything else I suggest a surrogate PK (use a [`serial` column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875517/939860)) and add a `UNIQUE` constraint to enforce uniqueness on `(cid, name, synonym)`.

If one of your `varchar` columns actually uses the maximum length you would exceed the maximum size for an index entry. See:

- [Character varying index overhead & length limit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69161/character-varying-index-overhead-length-limit/69164#69164)

I *guess* what you want is this, because it would make sense:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.name)
       c.name, min(s.synonym) AS min_synonym, s.cid
     , ts_rank(s.tsv_syns, c.lexemes, 16) AS rnk
     , count(*) AS ct
FROM   synonyms_all_gin_tsvcolumn s
JOIN   cmap5                      c ON c.lexemes @@ s.tsv_syns
GROUP  BY c.name, rnk, s.cid
ORDER  BY c.name, rnk DESC, ct DESC;
```

- I use explicit `[INNER] JOIN` with attached join condition replacing your `CROSS JOIN` plus `WHERE` clause. It's generally considered superior (easier to read and debug). I also use `rnk` as column name to avoid the basic function name `rank` as identifier.
- Group the results per `c.name` that have the same `rnk` and `s.cid`, take `min(s.synonym)` (for lack of definition in the question), and `count(*)` the peers per group.
- Reduce to one row per `c.name` with `DISTINCT ON` (Postgres specific extension of SQL standard `DISTINCT`), taking the highest rank first and, within same rank, the highest peer count. See:
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

Combining `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT ON` this way in one query level is possible since `DISTINCT` or `DISTINCT ON` are applied *after* `GROUP BY`.