# Character varying index overhead & length limit

Tags: postgresql, performance, index, disk-space, btree

I have a unique constraint on a character varying column that will mostly have lengths of approximately 600 but could get to 10 million.

I have read about [B-Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree), but I can't determine how much disk space the index will consume or if such large-sized values will prevent the index from functioning performantly.

What are the impacts upon disk space and time of a B-Tree index on character varying columns with such potentially large lengths?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Postgres, a unique constraint is implemented with a unique **B-tree index**. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS)

> Adding a unique constraint will automatically create a unique B-tree
> index on the column or group of columns used in the constraint.

Indexes use the same basic storing mechanisms as tables: arrays of data pages. Indexes have some minor additional features. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-page-layout.html)

> In a table, an item is a row; in an index, an item is an index entry.
>
> Every table and index is stored as an array of pages of a fixed size
> (usually 8 kB, although a different page size can be selected when
> compiling the server).

The maximum size of an index entry is roughly a third of a data page. See:

- [Why *not* ERROR: index row size xxxx exceeds maximum 2712 for index "foo"?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/217087/why-not-error-index-row-size-xxxx-exceeds-maximum-2712-for-index-foo)

The maximum size was reduced to **2704 bytes** in Postgres 12. Still the same in Postgres 15. Meaning your `UNIQUE` constraint **is not possible**.

Consider a unique index on hash value, either after adding a redundant column with the hash, or just an index on the hash expression.
You could use the built-in function [`md5()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) or something more efficient for huge values. Related:

- [Why doesn't my UNIQUE constraint trigger?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/299098/why-doesnt-my-unique-constraint-trigger/299107#299107)
- [Index max row size error](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25138/index-max-row-size-error)

Comment: Thank you Erwin Brandstetter, incredible advice as usual!  For performance, should I use `bytea`?  If so, should I let Postgres do the conversions with `md5` and `decode` or `sha512()` with this library http://www.zedwood.com/article/cpp-sha512-function?  I'm fairly certain I'll never need to extract the hash, but I will need to compare with external data.  Thank you so very much for sharing your great knowledge!

Comment: @Gracchus: I suggest you put that in new questions (one topic per piece). Comments are not the place. You can always link to this one for reference.

Comment: Thank you Erwin Brandstetter!  I have posted per your recommendation: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69170/optimal-hash-technique-to-index-large-text

Comment: I wonder if something has changed in newer Postgres version, as I can insert text values with 10000 (random) characters into a column using a unique index: http://rextester.com/ZDYS66763

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Interesting, indeed. Worthy of a new question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/217087/3684 (I think I found the answer.)

Comment: What about using hash indexes (on Postgresql 14)? Is that a better solution than using b-trees to index the md5 of the column?