# What is the optimal data type for an MD5 field?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, index, datatypes, uniqueidentifier

We are designing a system that is known to be read-heavy (on the order of tens of thousands of reads per minute).

- There is a table `names` that serves as a sort of central registry. Each row has a `text` field `representation` and a unique `key` that is an MD5 hash of that `representation`.<sup>1</sup> This table currently has tens of millions of records and is expected to grow into the billions over the lifetime of the application.
- There are dozens of other tables (of highly varying schemas and record counts) that make reference to the `names` table. Any given record in one of these tables is guaranteed to have a `name_key`, which is functionally a foreign key to the `names` table.

<sub>1: Incidentally, as you might expect, records in this table are immutable once written.</sub>

For any given table other than the `names` table, the most common query will follow this pattern:

```
SELECT list, of, fields 
FROM table 
WHERE name_key IN (md5a, md5b, md5c...);
```

I would like to optimize for read performance. I suspect that my first stop should be to minimize the size of the indices (though I wouldn't mind being proven wrong there).

**The Question:**
What is/are the optimal data types for the `key` and `name_key` columns?
Is there a reason to use `hex(32)` over `bit(128)`? `BTREE` or `GIN`?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The data type [**`uuid`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html) is perfectly suited for the task. It only occupies 16 bytes as opposed to 37 bytes in RAM for the `varchar` or `text` representation. (Or 33 bytes on disk, but the odd number would require padding in many cases to make it *40* bytes effectively.) And the `uuid` type has some more advantages.

Example:

```
SELECT md5('Store hash for long string, maybe for index?')::uuid AS md5_hash;
```

See:

- [Convert hex in text representation to decimal number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8335376/939860)
- [Would index lookup be noticeably faster with char vs varchar when all values are 36 chars](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89429/would-index-lookup-be-noticeably-faster-with-char-vs-varchar-when-all-values-are/89433#89433)

You might consider other (a bit cheaper) hashing functions if you don't need the cryptographic component of md5, but I would go with md5 for your use case. md5 is well established, very fast and your values are mostly read-only anyway.

A word of **warning**: For your case (`immutable once written`) a **functionally dependent (pseudo-natural) PK** is fine. But the same would be a *pain* where updates on `text` are possible. Think of correcting a typo: the PK and all depending indexes, FK columns in "dozens of other tables" and other references would have to change as well. Table and index bloat, locking issues, slow updates, lost references, ...

If `text` can change in normal operation, a [**surrogate PK**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) would be a better choice. I suggest a [**`bigserial`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) column with a range of -9223372036854775808 to +9223372036854775807. That's [nine quintillion two hundred twenty-three quadrillion three hundred seventy-two trillion thirty-six something billion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9223372036854775807)) distinct values for "billions of rows". Might be a good idea in any case: 8 instead of 16 bytes for dozens of FK columns and indexes!). Or a [random UUID](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/uuid-ossp.html) for *much* bigger cardinalities or distributed systems. You can always store said md5 (as `uuid`) additionally to find rows in the main table from the original text quickly.
Related:

- [Default value for UUID column in Postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/122623/default-value-for-uuid-column-in-postgres)

For your **query**, see:

- [Optimizing a Postgres query with a large IN](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91247/optimizing-a-postgres-query-with-a-large-in/91539#91539)

#### What about hyphens?

If you prefer a representation without hyphens, remove the hyphens for display:

```
SELECT replace('90b7525e-84f6-4850-c2ef-b407fae3f271', '-', '')
```

But I wouldn't bother. The default representation is just fine. And the problem's really not the representation here.

If other parties should have a different approach and throw strings without hyphens into the mix, that's no problem, either. Postgres accepts several reasonable text representations as input for a `uuid`. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html):

> PostgreSQL also accepts the following alternative forms for input: use
> of upper-case digits, the standard format surrounded by braces,
> omitting some or all hyphens, adding a hyphen after any group of four
> digits. Examples are:
>
> ```
> A0EEBC99-9C0B-4EF8-BB6D-6BB9BD380A11
> {a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11}
> a0eebc999c0b4ef8bb6d6bb9bd380a11
> a0ee-bc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9-bd38-0a11
> {a0eebc99-9c0b4ef8-bb6d6bb9-bd380a11}
> ```

#### Why not `bytea`?

The `md5()` function returns `text`. You would use [`decode()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) to convert to `bytea` and the default representation of *that* is:

```
SELECT decode(md5('Store hash for long string, maybe for index?'), 'hex')

\220\267R^\204\366HP\302\357\264\007\372\343\362q
```

You would have to `encode()` again to get the original text representation:

```
SELECT encode(my_md5_as_bytea, 'hex');
```

To top it off, values stored as `bytea` would occupy 20 bytes in RAM (and 17 bytes on disk, [24 with padding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7431468/939860)) due to the [internal `varlena` overhead](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-binary.html), which is particularly unfavorable for size and performance of simple indexes.

#### What about "invalid" UUIDs?

There are no "invalid" UUIDs.

Octet 13 and 17 encode a "version" and "variant" for certain UUID types. But Postgres' `uuid` data type accepts all 128-bit quantities without regard to "version" or "variant". That's according to [RFC 4122](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122):

> Validation mechanism:
> Apart from determining whether the timestamp portion of the UUID
> is in the future and therefore not yet assignable, there is no
> mechanism for determining whether a UUID is 'valid'.

"Version" and "variant" are meaningless / not applicable for this use case. To verify I ran a quick test:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4c97cc5ba261ffb4be85e1c76be9d4b2)*

***Everything*** works in favor of a `uuid` here.

Comment: Is this legit for "uuid"?  Please excuse me if I'm too pedantic, but I think what I'm seeing is that the "uuid" data type is oriented towards storing numbers that are 16 octets in length in binary format.  But the term "uuid" suggests a particular generation/hashing algorithm as well as the conventional textual representation in 5 blocks of dash-separated hexadecimal characters.  If this type name strongly suggests the UUID/GUID generation, isn't it a bit misleading, for programmers at least, to use this type for storing a hash?

Comment: @AndrewWolfe: Totally legit, IMO. Don't get carried away by the *name*. It's a 16-byte entity with a convenient set of provided type casts and input / output logic. The case at hand even actually requires a "unique identifier". You can store all kinds of character data in `text` columns as well - even if it's not a "text" at all.

Comment: isnt UUID of the form xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx how is postgres storing the ids that violate the 4 and y parts?

Comment: @PirateApp: There are no "invalid" UUIDs among 128-bit quantities. I added a bit to elaborate on that.

Answer (score 2):

I would store the MD5 in a `text` or `varchar` column. There is no performance difference between the various character data types. You might want to constrain the length of the md5 values by using `varchar(xxx)` to make sure the md5 value never exceeds a certain length.

Large IN lists are usually not really fast, it's better to do something like this:

```
with md5vals (md5) as (
  values ('one'), ('two'), ('three')
)
select t.*
from the_table t
  join md5vals m on t.name_key  = m.md5;
```

Another option that is sometimes said to be faster is to use an array:

```
select t.*
from the_table t
where name_key = ANY (array['one', 'two', 'three']);
```

As you are just comparing for equality, a regular BTree index should be fine. Both queries should be able to make use of such an index (especially if the are selecting only a small fraction of the rows.

Comment: Any particular reason not to use bit(128) or hex(32)? Values are guaranteed to fit neatly into such a field, and I'd like to protect from bad values being assigned.

Comment: @bobocopy: there is no "hex" data type in Postgres. I have never used the `bit` type so I can't comment on that. Given your expected number of rows, Erwin's suggestion seems to be better because of the space saving you get with storing this as UUID

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use 4 INTEGER or 2 BIGINT columns.

Comment: In terms of storage size, either option would fit, of course, but how convenient would it be to work with? Perhaps you could expand your answer to show an example or otherwise explain that.