# Default value for UUID column in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, default-value, uuid

In [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org) 9.x, for a column of type [`UUID`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-uuid.html), how do I specify a UUID to be generated automatically as a default value for any row insert?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

## tl;dr

Call `DEFAULT` when defining a column to invoke one of the [*OSSP uuid*](http://www.ossp.org/pkg/lib/uuid/) functions. The Postgres server will automatically invoke the function every time a row is inserted.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl 
(
  pkey UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v1() , 
  CONSTRAINT pkey_tbl PRIMARY KEY ( pkey )
)
```

If you already use the [*pgcrypto*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html) extension, consider the [Answer by bpieck](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/223124/19079).

## Plugin Required To Generate UUID

While [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org) out-of-the-box supports *storing* [UUID (Universally Unique Identifier)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID) values in their native [128-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/128-bit) form, *generating* UUID values requires a plug-in. In Postgres, a plug-in is known as an `extension`.

To install an extension, call [`CREATE EXTENSION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createextension.html). To avoid re-installing, add `IF NOT EXISTS`. See [my blog post](http://crafted-software.blogspot.com/2011/10/extensions-in-postgres.html) for more details, or see [this page in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12505158/642706).

The extension we want is an open-source library built in C for working with UUIDs, [*OSSP uuid*](http://www.ossp.org/pkg/lib/uuid/). A [build of this library for Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/uuid-ossp.html) is often bundled with an installation of Postgres such as the [graphical installers provided](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload) by [Enterprise DB](http://www.enterprisedb.com) or included by cloud providers such as [Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/postgresql/).

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```

## Generating Various Kinds Of UUID

See the [extension’s doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/uuid-ossp.html) to see a list of multiple commands offered for generating various kinds of UUID values. To get the original version of UUID built from the computer’s [MAC address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) plus current date-time plus a small random value, call [`uuid_generate_v1()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/uuid-ossp.html).

```
SELECT uuid_generate_v1();
```

> 672124b6-9894-11e5-be38-001d42e813fe

Later variations on this theme were developed for alternate kinds of UUIDs. Some people may not want to record the server’s actual MAC address, for example, for security or privacy concerns. The Postgres extension generates five kinds of UUIDs, plus the “nil” UUID `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`.

## UUID As Default Value

That method call can be made automatically to generate a default value for any newly inserted row. When defining the column, specify:

> `DEFAULT uuid_generate_v1()`

See that command used in the following example table definition.

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.pet_
(
  species_ text NOT NULL,
  name_ text NOT NULL,
  date_of_birth_ text NOT NULL,
  uuid_ uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v1(),  -- <====
  CONSTRAINT pet_pkey_ PRIMARY KEY (uuid_)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.pet_
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

## UUID versions

The [*uuid-ossp*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/uuid-ossp.html) plugin can generate [various versions of UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Versions).

- `uuid_generate_v1()`
  Contains [MAC address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) of current computer + current moment. Commonly used, but avoid if you are sensitive about disclosing the MAC of your database server or the time when this value was generated. Defined by specification as a [Version 1 UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_(date-time_and_MAC_address)).
- `uuid_generate_v1mc()`
  Like [Version 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_(date-time_and_MAC_address)), but with a random multicast MAC address instead of the real MAC address. Apparently a way to use Version 1 but substituting another MAC rather than the actual MAC of your database server if you are sensitive about disclosing that fact.
  What is a ‘random multicast MAC’? [I do not know exactly](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/175318/19079). After reading section 4.1.6 of [RFC 4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122), I suspect this is a random number used in place of the MAC but with bits set to indicate a multicast MAC address rather than the usual unicast so as to distinguish this variation of Version 1 from a usual real-MAC Version 1 UUID.
- `uuid_generate_v3( namespace uuid, name text )`
  Contains an [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) of text you provide. Defined by specification as a [Version 3 UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Versions_3_and_5_(namespace_name-based)), [namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace)-based UUID.
- `uuid_generate_v4()`
  Based on randomly-generated data for 121-122 of the 128 bits. Six or seven [bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit) used to indicate Version & Variant. This kind of UUID is practical only if implemented with a [cryptographically-strong random generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator). Defined by specification as a [Version 4 UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)).
- `uuid_generate_v5( namespace uuid, name text )`
  Same as Version 3 but using [SHA1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA1) hashing. Defined by specification as [Version 5 UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Versions_3_and_5_(namespace_name-based)).
- `uuid_nil()`
  A special case, all bits set to zero `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`. Used as a flag for an unknown UUID value. Known as a [nil UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Nil_UUID).

To compare types, see Question, [Which UUID version to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20342058/642706)

If you are interested only in Version 4 (randomly generated), and are already using *pgcrypto*, see the [Answer by bpieck](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/223124/19079).

If you are curious about Versions 3 & 5, see this Question, [Generating v5 UUID. What is name and namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10867405/642706).

For more discussion, see [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19751613) to a similar Question and my blog post [*UUID values from JDBC to Postgres*](http://crafted-software.blogspot.com/2013/03/uuid-values-from-jdbc-to-postgres.html).

Comment: 1,000,000 hits in Google for how to create columns of type UUID. Zero hits for how to freaking query rows by that pk!! :-@

Comment: @ClintEastwood [My Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19751613) to a similar Question and my blog post [*UUID values from JDBC to Postgres*](http://crafted-software.blogspot.com/2013/03/uuid-values-from-jdbc-to-postgres.html) might help you with that. If those prove to be insufficient, post a new Question. I’d be happy to take another stab at it. I understand your frustration!

Comment: @ClintEastwood: the syntax to compare a UUID column with a value follows the syntax for constants documented in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS and type casts: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS

Comment: @BasilBourque: It's not really necessary to cast the result of `getObject()` you can also use `UUID id = rs.getObject("uuid_", UUID.class);`

Comment: Wouldn't the "cryptographically-strong random generator" be implemented by `uuid_generate_v4()` itself? How can I know if it's cryptographically strong?

Comment: @Rokit To verify the strength of the random number generator, look to the underlying open-source implementation that is wrapped by this Postgres extension, the [*OSSP uuid*](http://www.ossp.org/pkg/lib/uuid/) library project as mentioned in my Answer. And remember, Version 4 UUIDs should be used only as a last resort, if for some reason you cannot choose the other types. Generally, your first choice should be the Version 1 kind, by calling either `uuid_generate_v1` or `uuid_generate_v1mc`.

Comment: Setting the default value doesn't seem to work in PG10

Comment: @ÁkosVandra  Are you sure you activated the extension? Did you try using it with a `SELECT uuid_generate_v1() ;`? If so post a Question with all the details. But first double-check your work. I  suspect user-error, not a Postgres bug.

Comment: Sorry, disregard, it does work, my query was wrong.

Comment: I have a question here, what happens if i dont use any of these? Im still getting a generated uuid and it is working.. which version is it ?

Comment: @user1354825 How are you generating the UUID? What function call?

Comment: im not any function call at all!! Im actually using hibernate and my entity is marked as uuid type in my spring application, so was wondering if postgres has a default version for generation ? or in this case hibernate is doing the job?

Comment: @user1354825 Postgres 13 & 14 have a [command built-in](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-uuid.html) for Version 4 (random) UUID. Otherwise the usual route is by either plug-in, *pgcrypto* or *uuid-ossp*, as discussed on this page.

Answer (score 28):

## *pgcrypto* extension

Just a small addition to Basil’s very [detailed answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/122624/19079).

Since currently most are using [pgcrypto](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html), instead of `uuid_generate_v4()` you can use [`gen_random_uuid()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html#id-1.11.7.34.9) for a [Version 4 UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)) value.

First, enable *pgcrypto* in your Postgres.

```
CREATE EXTENSION "pgcrypto";
```

Just set DEFAULT of a column to

```
DEFAULT gen_random_uuid()
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, are there performance differences between the two?

Comment: Generated 100mil uuids using both methods, they come in at pretty much the same ~9sec. (Tested under Postgres 14 - which doesnt require the pgcrypto extension anymore for this function)

Answer (score 12):

If using Postgres 13 or newer you do not need any modifications or extra plugins and can just use `gen_random_uuid()`

just tested on default AWS Aurora Serverless v2 with Postgres v14

p.s. you can see my default id is actually with prefix `wor-` while it's workspace id. I add prefixes to all tables so when i get ID from anywhere - logs, support etc. i can tell exactly what to search for.

`concat('wor-', gen_random_uuid())`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also works with Postgres v13. See [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-uuid.html)

Comment: Yes, 13+, thanks for noticing will update