# What are the drawbacks of using DOMAINS to store metadata about the column?

Tags: postgresql, domain

I came across [a question about a data type for MD5 values](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115271/what-is-the-optimal-data-type-for-an-md5-field). The recommendation in that question states using `uuid` as type for that field.

The argumentation is solid. But I find that this might be confusing to someone unaware of the points revealed in the above question. The decision to use `uuid` as MD5 type is something that I would like to see in some form of documentation in any project that does this.

As a "helper" to whoever looks into the DB Schema, one could argue to create a `md5` domain inheriting from `uuid`. That way, the column types would be much more explicit and the intention would be much clearer.

But it would use a domain for no other reason than to "rename" an existing type.

It's still something that would make sense to document properly. But that documentation could be centralised to a section explaining the domains in the DB. So you wouldn't gain anything in terms of documentation. The advantage I see is, as mentioned, that the *intention* becomes clear when looking at the table DDL.

Are there any downsides to this?

Comment: Using a domain for that makes sense. One downside is however, that you can no longer change the definition of a domain as long as it is used by at least one column. E.g. a domain defined as `varchar(10)` can not be changed to `varchar(20)` if it's used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's not a *bad* idea to store the meta-data as the type name, I would not. That's a slippery slope that will lead to bizzare place where `int`s become more specific types that provide nothing (insofar as constraints, what DOMAINs are for). This meta-data about what is **in** the column belongs in the *column name*, not the *type.*

Further you can explain it with a PostgreSQL `COMMENT`

```
COMMENT ON COLUMN mycatalog.myschema.mytable IS
  $$ Not really a UUID, just suing it to store an MD5 $$;
```

## Inability to change underlying types

From a_horse_with_no_name,

- You can no longer change the definition of a domain as long as it is used by at least one column. E.g. a domain defined as varchar(10) can not be changed to varchar(20) if it's used.

## Other problems

- There are some oddities regarding ranges over [domains](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/176476/2639)
- For any functions that use the domain, you will want to ensure that the types from literals are in the domain type.

  ```
  CREATE DOMAIN foo AS text;
  CREATE FUNCTION f(foo)
  RETURNS bool
  AS $$
    SELECT false
  $$ LANGUAGE SQL;

  SELECT f('foo'); -- returns false

  CREATE FUNCTION f(text)
  RETURNS bool
  AS $$
    SELECT true;
  $$ LANGUAGE SQL;

  SELECT f('foo'); -- returns true
  ```

---

I use domains liberally, but only to add constraints so that they're centrally managed and not in a hodgepodge of CHECK statements.