# Ranges over domains do not trigger implicit casting

Tags: postgresql, cast, range-types, gist-index, domain

As far as I was able to find out, it is currently not possible in PostgreSQL v9.5 (and above?) to obtain implicit casting with custom range types. To illustrate,
when I define the following demo setup:

```
drop schema if exists tac cascade;
create schema tac;

create domain tac.usascii_small_letters
  as text
  check ( value ~ '^[a-z]+$' );

create domain tac.ucid as integer
  check ( value between x'0'::integer and x'10ffff'::integer );

create function tac.ucid_rng_diff( cid_1 tac.ucid, date_2 tac.ucid )
  returns double precision
  language sql
  immutable
  as $$
    select cast( cid_1 - date_2 as double precision );
  $$;

-- A ----------------------------------------------------------------
create type tac.ucid_rng as range (
  subtype       = tac.ucid,
  subtype_diff  = tac.ucid_rng_diff
  );
-- ----------------------------------------------------------------

-- -- B ----------------------------------------------------------------
-- set role dba; -- !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
-- create type tac.ucid_rng;

-- create function tac.ucid_rng_canonical( x tac.ucid_rng )
--   returns tac.ucid_rng
--   language plpgsql
--   as $$
--     begin
--         if not lower_inc(x) then
--             x := tac.ucid_rng(lower(x) + 1, upper(x), '[]');
--         end if;
--         if not upper_inc(x) then
--             x := tac.ucid_rng(lower(x), upper(x) - 1, '[]');
--         end if;
--         return x;
--     end;
--   $$;

-- create type tac.ucid_rng as range (
--   subtype       = tac.ucid
--   , subtype_diff  = tac.ucid_rng_diff
--   , canonical     = tac.ucid_rng_canonical
--   );

-- reset role; -- !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
-- -- ----------------------------------------------------------------

create table tac.words (
  word                    tac.usascii_small_letters,
  cid                     tac.ucid,
  cid_range               tac.ucid_rng
  );

insert into tac.words values
  ( 'foo', 1, '[11,21]' ),
  ( 'bar', 2, '[12,22]' ),
  ( 'zip', 3, '[13,23]' ),
  ( 'dat', 4, '[14,24]' ),
  ( 'baz', 5, '[15,25]' );

select * from tac.words where word between 'a' and 'c';
select * from tac.words where word between 'a'::tac.usascii_small_letters and 'c';
select * from tac.words where cid between 3 and 5;
select * from tac.words where cid_range @> '[17,23]';
select * from tac.words where cid_range @> '[17,23]'::tac.ucid_rng;
select * from tac.words where cid_range @> 23::tac.ucid;
select * from tac.words where cid_range @> 23;
```

and run it as is with block A but without block B, I get

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer <@ tac.ucid_rng
LINE 1: select * from tac.words where cid_range @> 23;
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s).
You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

The tests show that a lot of things using custom domains / types do work with implicit casting. Indeed, I can do a kind-of range check against my custom string data type, and even `cid_range @> '[17,23]'` works. It is *only* `cid_range @> 23` that mysteriously fails.

Now I tried to implement a suitable canonicalization function for my `tac.cid_rng` type; however, as remarked in https://stackoverflow.com/a/29939205, that's not gonna fly:

```
NOTICE:  argument type tac.ucid_rng is only a shell
NOTICE:  return type tac.ucid_rng is only a shell
ERROR:  PL/pgSQL functions cannot return type tac.ucid_rng
```

So it would seem that it's still impossible in PostgreSQL 9.5 to have a custom range type with implicit casting in point-inclusion queries, although the type itself is defined quite transparently over a set of contiguous integers and similar queries work fine without any extra coding.

I'd like to know whether I missed something here, and what recommended ways there are to deal with the situation. I think I could just live with the explicit cast, or else write a function that does it for me.

The thing I don't get is why `cid_range @> '[17,23]'` works but `cid_range @> 23` fails—after all, a cast from generic / suggestive literal to actual data type has to be performed in both cases. It would appear from the tests that implicit casting from integer literal into the `tac.ucid` domain work as well, so it's hard to see what exactly is missing that necessitates a piece of C boiler plate code that does nothing but a generic check and integer increment / decrement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a bug and you should report it. I think it can be demonstrated a lot easier.

```
SELECT '[1,5]'::int4range @> 3;

CREATE DOMAIN zdomain AS int;
CREATE TYPE myrange_int     AS RANGE ( subtype = int );
CREATE TYPE myrange_zdomain AS RANGE ( subtype = zdomain );

-- WORKS
SELECT '[1,5]'::myrange_int     @> 3;
SELECT '[1,5]'::myrange_zdomain @> 3::zdomain;

-- DOES NOT WORK
SELECT '[1,5]'::myrange_zdomain @> 3;
ERROR:  operator does not exist: myrange_zdomain @> integer
LINE 1: SELECT '[1,5]'::myrange_zdomain @> 3;
                                          ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I think what you want is totally reasonable. I don't think it's going to be a high priority item. My assumption is that coercion that is triggered is not looking to see if the range is over a domain, and it should.

**Feel free to update your question with my example, I think it'll be a lot easier for people to follow**

Comment: Nice to find out...