# Composite constraint of numrange and boolean

Tags: postgresql, database-design, postgresql-9.4, constraint, exclusion-constraint

I have a current constraint like this:

```
ALTER TABLE myschema.my_table ADD CONSTRAINT my_constraint EXCLUDE USING gist((<uuidcol>::text) WITH =, numrange(<start>, <end>) WITH &&);
```

This works fine, but I need to add one more thing to the constraint, it must only be enforced for rows where a `boolean` column is true (let's call it `active`). I tried this:

```
ALTER TABLE myschema.my_table ADD CONSTRAINT my_constraint EXCLUDE USING gist((<uuidcol>::text) WITH =, numrange(<start>, <end>) WITH && active = TRUE);
```

This throws syntax error:

> ```
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "active"
> SQL state: 42601
> ```

Is it possible to have the constraint include the `active` column as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `WHERE` clause to make it a ***partial*** `EXCLUSION` constraint (creating a partial index to implement it):

```
ALTER TABLE myschema.my_table ADD CONSTRAINT my_constraint
  EXCLUDE USING gist ((uuidcol::text) WITH =, numrange(start, end) WITH &&)
  WHERE (active);
```

The parentheses are not optional. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE)

> The predicate allows you to specify an exclusion constraint on a
>   subset of the table; internally this creates a partial index. Note
>   that parentheses are required around the predicate.

BTW, in **Postgres 10** or later you can install the additional module [`btree_gist`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-gist.html) to add (among others) the necessary operator class for type `uuid` in GiST indexes. So you can simplify:

```
ALTER TABLE myschema.my_table ADD CONSTRAINT my_constraint
  EXCLUDE USING gist (uuidcol WITH =, numrange(start, end) WITH &&)
  WHERE (active);
```

Considerably more efficient than casting to `text`. Related:

- [What is the optimal data type for an MD5 field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115271/what-is-the-optimal-data-type-for-an-md5-field/115316#115316)