# How to enforce UNIQUE constraint for sixth normal form in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-design, normalization, constraint, exclusion-constraint

I have a table `person` which I am planing to normalize to the sixth normal form.
The table has attributes `username`, `email`, and `phone`. The reason I want to go to the sixth normal form is keeping the change history of these columns and adding additional metadata to them (e.g. the confidence level about the data).

I am planning to create new tables `person_username`, `person_email`, `person_phone` and have the `person` view which brings them all together and has `INSTEAD OF` triggers so that users can insert and update the view and these changes get directed to the underlying tables.

My question in, how to enforce `UNIQUE` constraints when using the sixth normal form.
The structure of the `person_email` table would look something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person_email (
    person_id integer FOREIGN KEY person(id),
    username text NOT NULL,
    valid_from datetime
);
```

The data in the table might look like this:

| person_id | username | valid_from |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **foo** | **2022-01-01** |
| 1 | bar | 2021-06-01 |
| **2** | **foo** | **2020-08-01** |
| 2 | abc | 2020-02-01 |

The rows marked as bold hold the most recent (the current) information. Both users 1 and 2 have the current username set to `foo` which should not be allowed. However, I cannot make `username` `UNIQUE`, since the fact that someone had used that name in the distant past does not mean that someone else could not use it now.

What I would need would be a `UNIQUE (username)` constraint which would only look at the most recent row for each user. How to achieve that? Is there a way to make use of the PostgreSQL `EXCLUDE` constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use an [**exclusion constraint**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION).

You'll need to install the additional module [`btree_gist`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-gist.html) to add an operator class we need for the multicolumn index backing the constraint.

There is no data type *"datetime"* like you display. Your values indicate `date`, so I'll go with that. (The actual data type matters for the implementation!)

Also, your table design with just `valid_from` generally works. `valid_to` can be derived from the next row. But for the purpose of an exclusion constraint, we need `valid_to` in the same row. So add that (redundantly).

```
ALTER TABLE person_email ADD CONSTRAINT person_email_no_username_overlap
EXCLUDE USING gist (username WITH =, daterange(valid_from, valid_to, '[]') WITH &&);
```

This way, the same username can never be in use in overlapping time ranges.

Note how I made upper and lower bound *inclusive* with `'[]'`. Adapt to your needs. There are subtle differences for different data types.

`NULL` as lower or upper bound means "unbounded".

Alternatively, you could use a `daterange` column to begin with. Either has pros and cons.

Related:

- [How to use the NOW() function as upper bound of a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56690941/939860)
- [Why does PostgreSQL consider NULL boundaries in range types to be distinct from infinite boundaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67612325/939860)
- [Find overlapping date ranges in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15305292/939860)
- [Composite constraint of numrange and boolean](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193688/composite-constraint-of-numrange-and-boolean/193691#193691)