# Definition of indexing, datatype configuration, and DBMS for SHA3-256 hashes

Tags: database-design, index, datatypes, hashing

I am designing a system within which I will need to be able to search a database using a file or string SHA3-256 hash.

For example the hash of **test** is

```
36f028580bb02cc8272a9a020f4200e346e276ae664e45ee80745574e2f5ab80
```

1. Which **DATATYPE** should I set the column that stores this value? I've heard about using BINARY instead of VARCHAR.
2. How should I **index** this column so that searches by hash are fastest?
3. Which **database management system** (like PostgreSQL, DB2, SQL Server), or **document software** (like MongoDB) should I use that most efficiently allows me to store and retrieve records by hash? I only have experience with relational database management systems like MySQL, but maybe a document store like MongoDB would be the better way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SHA3-256 is 256bits. That's 32 **bytes.**

- Don't store it as `TEXT` any form, or it'll be 256 **bytes** (8x the size).
- I would store it as inline binary if your database supports it because I doubt anything it's going to have a data type for a 32 byte data type (which nothing uses except AVX2).

On indexing, any HASH index would work if your database provides it.

From PostgreSQL,

```
CREATE DOMAIN sha3_256 AS bytea;

CREATE TABLE datastore (
  id     int  PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  myhash sha3_256
);

CREATE INDEX ON datastore USING HASH (myhash);

INSERT INTO datastore (id,myhash) VALUES
  (1, decode('36f028580bb02cc8272a9a020f4200e346e276ae664e45ee80745574e2f5ab80', 'hex'));
```

---

As a special optimization you could store it as [two `UUIDs`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/115316/2639). Though I probably wouldn't bother.