# Find the greatest difference between each unique record with different timestamps

Tags: postgresql, order-by, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions, rank

I have a PostgreSQL table with the following schema and data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS T(
     id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
     username varchar(15),
     person varchar(10),
     tweets int,
     followers int,
     following int,
     likes int,
     created_at date) 
;
 
 id                                   | username     | person     | tweets | followers | following | likes | created_at
 :----------------------------------- | :----------- | :--------- | -----: | --------: | --------: | ----: | :---------
 3fa34100-d688-4051-a687-ec49d05e7212 | renok        | null       |    110 |         6 |         0 |     0 | 2020-10-10
 bab9ceb9-2770-49ea-8489-77e5d763a223 | Lydia_C      | test user2 |    515 |      1301 |      1852 |  1677 | 2020-10-10
 4649077a-9188-4821-a1ec-3b38608ea44a | Kingston_Sav | null       |   2730 |      1087 |      1082 |  1339 | 2020-10-10
 eef80836-e140-4adc-9598-8b612ab1825b | TP_s         | null       |   1835 |       998 |       956 |  1832 | 2020-10-10
 fd3ff8c7-0994-40b6-abe0-915368ab9ae5 | DKSnr4       | null       |    580 |       268 |       705 |   703 | 2020-10-10
 3fa34100-d688-4051-a687-ec49d05e7312 | renok        | null       |    119 |         6 |         0 |     0 | 2020-10-12
 bab9ceb9-2770-49ea-8489-77e5d763a224 | Lydia_C      | test user2 |    516 |      1301 |      1852 |  1687 | 2020-10-12
 4649077a-9188-4821-a1ec-3b38608ea44B | Kingston_Sav | null       |   2737 |      1090 |      1084 |  1342 | 2020-10-12
 eef80836-e140-4adc-9598-8b612ae1835c | TP_s         | null       |   1833 |       998 |       957 |  1837 | 2020-10-12
 fd3ff8c7-0994-40b6-abe0-915368ab7ab5 | DKSnr4       | null       |    570 |       268 |       700 |   703 | 2020-10-12
```

I intend to get the biggest difference between the most recent date and the next most recent date for each unique username and the find the username with the largest margin (difference) for example..In the above table the most recent date is `2020-10-12` and the next most recent date is `2020-10-10`.

So I want to get something like this

```
 id                                   | username     | person | tweets | followers | following | likes | created_at | prev_followers | gain
 :----------------------------------- | :----------- | :----- | -----: | --------: | --------: | ----: | :--------- | -------------: | ---:
 4649077a-9188-4821-a1ec-3b38608ea44a | Kingston_Sav | null   |   2737 |      1090 |      1084 |  1342 | 2020-10-12 |           1087 |    3
```

Comment: Aside: your column `id varchar(36)` looks like it could (better) be `id uuid PRIMARY KEY`. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/89433/3684,  https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/115316/3684

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ways lead to Rome. The below should be a good one (fast and flexible) to *"find the username with the largest margin"*

**Assuming** all involved columns are defined `NOT NULL`. And each username can only have *one* entry per day. Else you have to do more.

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT *, dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS rnk
   FROM   tbl
   )
SELECT d1.*
     , d2.followers AS prev_followers
     , d1.followers - d2.followers AS gain
FROM  (SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rnk = 1) d1
JOIN  (SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rnk = 2) d2 USING (username)
ORDER  BY gain DESC
        , d1.followers, username  -- added tiebreaker
LIMIT  1;
```

The CTE named `cte` attaches rank numbers with [`dense_rank()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) (not `rank()`, not `row_number()`). Then join the latest day (`rnk = 1`) with the one before (`rnk = 2`) and calculate the gain. Obviously, users must have entries for both days to qualify. Finally order by the gain and take the first row.

Note the added `ORDER BY` expressions to try and break possible ties: there can be multiple users with the same gain, so you have to define how to deal with that. One way is to add tiebreakes. In my example, a user with a smaller absolute number of followers is preferred (higher relative gain), and the alphabetically first wins if that's still ambiguous.

**Or** you return **all "winners"**:

Again, many ways ... **Postgres 13** added the standard SQL clause [`WITH TIES`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT) for that purpose exactly:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT *, dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS rnk
   FROM   tbl
   )
SELECT d1.*
     , d2.followers AS prev_followers
     , d1.followers - d2.followers AS gain
FROM  (SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rnk = 1) d1
JOIN  (SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rnk = 2) d2 USING (username)
ORDER  BY gain DESC
FETCH  FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=42ffe290e8a8d113c28f6898677718e8)*

Detailed explanation for `WITH TIES`:

- [Greater than or equal to ALL() and equal to MAX() speed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63184287/939860)

Comment: This is a very good answer and it works but some columns for example person can be null and is indeed expected to be null for some specific usecase. I picked your answer over @akina's answer because for cases where there is a tie i.e there are two records with the same highest gain, your answer will show the both of them.

Comment: Here's a fiddle comparing both of your given solutions. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=daadb4deea204dfbee517cfd8d9538cb

Comment: Here's an [analysis](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8bc005200d63f1e9ac3d93b4fcc9e389) of both answers

Comment: `person` can be NULL, it's just payload. If one of the columns used to sort or join can be NULL, you need to understand NULL and may need to do more. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9511492/939860. Please remember to provide relevant table definitions showing data types and constraints (`CREATE TABLE` statement) in questions. A fiddle serves well, too.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT DISTINCT created_at
          FROM t
          ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 2 ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT src.*, 
                 LEAD(src.followers) OVER (PARTITION BY src.id 
                                           ORDER BY src.created_at DESC) prev_followers,
                 src.followers - LEAD(src.followers) OVER (PARTITION BY src.id 
                                                           ORDER BY src.created_at DESC) gain
          FROM t src
          JOIN cte1 ON src.created_at = cte1.created_at )
SELECT *
FROM cte2
WHERE gain IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY gain DESC LIMIT 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b4e9d9970e63cff69740905b6b6ceff4)

---

> whenever there are two records with the same difference margin..It always shows one instead of two.

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT DISTINCT created_at
          FROM t
          ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 2 ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT src.*, 
                 LEAD(src.followers) OVER (PARTITION BY src.id 
                                           ORDER BY src.created_at DESC) prev_followers,
                 src.followers - LEAD(src.followers) OVER (PARTITION BY src.id 
                                                           ORDER BY src.created_at DESC) gain
          FROM t src
          JOIN cte1 ON src.created_at = cte1.created_at ),
cte3 AS ( SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY gain DESC) rnk
          FROM cte2
          WHERE gain IS NOT NULL )
SELECT *
FROM cte3
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2e665855bda74bbdb0f9ca1497426940)

Comment: Hello @Akina that is not what I want. When I run your solution this is what I get https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ae0976eafa089337fb43ac9e4e551fb3

Comment: @basebandit Edited. Check.

Comment: thank you it now works as expected however whenever there are two records with the same difference margin..It always shows one instead of two. Had to change limit to 2 for such scenarios.

Comment: @basebandit *Had to change limit to 2 for such scenarios.* ??? and what if there are 3 rows to be returned? Updated, look.

Comment: It now takes into account such scenarios. Both your answers are correct.