# Index row size 2976 exceeds in postgresql

Tags: postgresql-14

We have seen some of the indexes are getting failing with below error.

ERROR:  index row size 2976 exceeds byte version 4 maximum 2704 for index "idx1"
HINT:  Values larger than 1/3 of a buffer page cannot be indexed.
Consider a function index of an MD5 hash of the value, or use full text indexing.

Index :
Create index idx1 on table1 using btree(upper(col1));

Table column length:
4000
pg_column_size for that column:
2931

Can you please suggest how to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

> Can you please suggest how to fix this issue

Sure:

> Consider a function index of an MD5 hash of the value, or use full text indexing.

There is a [limit to the size of an index](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69164/150011) based on the length of the column because of how much data can fit inside a data page. That limit is 2,704 bytes (roughly 1/3rd the size of an 8 KB page).

This is why you get the error:

> ERROR: index row size 2976 exceeds byte version 4 maximum 2704 for index "idx1"